# UIPanGestureRecognizer does not work

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

It's weird, but when I add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to a view it does not work. It's my view, that white view is a subview of the red view:

[image]

**Main View:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var whiteView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(ViewController.handlePan))
    whiteView.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer]        
}


func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)  {
    //foo
}
```

When I tap and drag the white view it won't move.

Comment: It's a PangestureRecognizer, not TapgestureRecognizer???

Comment: What's the question? You have assigned the gesture recognizer to the white view.

Comment: @t0mm13b, i cannot move the white view, it's the problem.

Comment: My problem was I created a `UIGestureRecognizer` instead of a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var redView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var whiteView: UIView!

    var lastLocation:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:#selector(ViewController.handlePan))
        whiteView.addGestureRecognizer(panRecognizer)

    }


    func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)  {
        let translation  = recognizer.translationInView(redView)
        whiteView.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation.x + translation.x, lastLocation.y + translation.y)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        // Promote the touched view
        lastLocation = whiteView.center

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
whiteView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple's docs:

If the code for your pan gesture recognizer **is not called**, check to see if the **following conditions** are true, and make corrections as needed:

The **isUserInteractionEnabled** property of the view **is set to true**. Image views and labels set this property to false by default.

The **number of touches** is between the values specified in the **minimumNumberOfTouches** and **maximumNumberOfTouches** properties.

For a **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer** object, the edges property is configured and touches start at the appropriate edge.

[Handling Pan Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_uikit_gestures/handling_pan_gestures)

Answer (score -3):

If you are using swift language for method you can't use `[]`.

```
var PanGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToPanGesture:")
whiteView.addGestureRecognizer(PanGesture)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not the problem